# Laravel and Twitter API - Any suggestions on how to post tweets?

Tags: php, twitter, laravel

Recently I started looking into Laravel 4 and wanted to make a little application to post tweets for me. I can't seem to find a good library though, or perhaps I am not using them properly.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a good twitter API library to use with Laravel, and how to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good tutorial using the thujohn/twitter-l4 package.

The tutorial can be found here: http://creative-punch.net/2014/02/post-random-tweets-laravel-twitter-api/

It goes in-depth on using the library to create an application to post random tweets with Laravel 4 and should cover everything you asked for.

Comment: That was a really in-depth tutorial, I would have recommended the same!